# How to trigger something when a game property equals a (certain value)

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, properties

How do I trigger something when a game property equals a certain value?
So Here is what I have done.

```
myprop = own['prop']
if myprop == 50:
    own.applyRotation((0, 0, 0.5),True)
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Can you use logic bricks?

Answer (score 1):

The script is checking if prop is an integer equal to 50, but the property is actually a string.

**Solution 1**

Change String to Integer in the Properties panel

**Solution 2**

Change

```
if myprop == 50:
```

To

```
if myprop == '50':
```

Going forward if you enable the console (Window -> Toggle System Console) it will let you know when these sort of errors happen.